# Custom delivery range wrong data on WooCommerce Order received page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have this custom code in WooCommerce that displays a calculated delivery date range based on the products availability in the cart page, the checkout page and the Order received page (thankyou page).

The code below is working fine except on Order received page (thankyou page) where the estimated delivery range data is wrong…

Any help on this. How to get the correct estimated delivery range data on Order received page?

Here is this code:

```
// The function that calculate the delivery dates range (Not hooked)
function calculate_delivery_range() { 

    $all_items_in_stock = true; // initializing

    // Iterating through cart items (to get the stock info)
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {

        # HANDLING SIMPLE AND VARIABLE PRODUCTS

        // Variable products
        $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
        if( 0 != $variation_id) {
            $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
            $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
        } else {
            // Simple products
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $product_obj = new WC_Product($product_id);
            $stock = $product_obj->get_stock_quantity();
        }

        if( $stock <= 0 ){
            // if an item is out of stock
            $all_items_in_stock = false;
            break; // We break the loop
        }
    }

    // Items "in stock" (1 to 4 week days)
    if( $all_items_in_stock ){
        for( $start=0, $count=-1 ; $count < 4; $start++ ){
            $weekdays = date('w', strtotime("+$start days"));
            if( $weekdays > 0 && $weekdays < 6 ){
                $count++;
//            echo date('D j (w)', strtotime("+$start days")).', ';
                if($count == 1){
                    $from = date('D, d.m.', strtotime("+$start days") );
                } elseif($count == 4) {
                    $to = date('D, d.m.', strtotime("+$start days") );
                }
            }
        }
    } else { // One or more Items are Out of stock (14 to 21 week days)
        for( $start=0, $count=-1 ; $count < 21; $start++ ){
            $weekdays = date('w', strtotime("+$start days"));
            if( $weekdays > 0 && $weekdays < 6 ){
                $count++;
                if($count == 14){
                    $from = date('D, d.m.', strtotime("+$start days") );
                } elseif($count == 21) {
                    $to = date('D, d.m.', strtotime("+$start days") );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ## TRANSLATION ##

    // DAYS IN ENGLISH (Source)
    $days_en = array( 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri' );

    // TRANSLATE the DAYS in GERMAN (replacement)
    $days_ge = array( 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr' );

    $from = str_replace($days_en, $days_ge, $from);
    $to   = str_replace($days_en, $days_ge, $to);

    // Return the "from" and "to" values in an array
    return array( 'from' => $from, 'to' => $to );
}

// Displaying the dates delivery range in Cart, Checkout and Order reiceived pages
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'lieferzeit'); // cart page
add_action ( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'lieferzeit'); // checkout page
add_action ( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'lieferzeit'); // Order recieved
function lieferzeit() {

    // Calling the "delivery date range calculation"
    $days_range = calculate_delivery_range();

    ## DISPLAYING ##
    echo '<i class="shipping_icon fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></i> <div class="lieferung"> Vorauslichtliche Lieferung </div>  <div class="fromto_date"> ' . $days_range['from'] . ' – ' . $days_range['to'] . ' </div> <div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Gilt nur bei Lieferungen nach Deutschland.</span></div>' ;

}


add_action ( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'include_delivery_range_hidden_checkout_fields');
function include_delivery_range_hidden_checkout_fields() {

    // Calling the "delivery date range calculation"
    $days_range = calculate_delivery_range();

    // Output hidden imput fields with delivery dates range values
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="delivery_range_from" value="'.$days_range['from'].'">
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_range_to" value="'.$days_range['to'].'">';

}

// Save the "delivery range values" in order meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_delivery_range_in_order_meta',  100, 1 );
function save_delivery_range_in_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    $delivery_range_from = $_POST['delivery_range_from'];
    if ( ! empty( $delivery_range_from ) )
        add_post_meta( $order_id, '_delivery_range_from', $delivery_range_from );

    $delivery_range_to = $_POST['delivery_range_to'];
    if ( ! empty( $delivery_range_to ) )
        add_post_meta( $order_id, '_delivery_range_to', $delivery_range_to );

}

// Adding Delivery range metabox to Order edit pages
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_order_delivery_range_meta_boxe' );
function add_order_delivery_range_meta_boxe(){
    add_meta_box(
        'woocommerce-order-delivery-range-values', __( 'Voraussichtliche Lieferung', 'woocommerce' ),
        'order_delivery_range_values', 'shop_order', 'side', 'default'
    );
}

// Adding content to Delivery range metabox to Order edit pages
function order_delivery_range_values(){
    global $post;

    $from = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_delivery_range_from', true);
    $to = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_delivery_range_to', true);

    echo "<p>$from - $to</p>";
}
```

Here are some screenshots of the change of the delivery dates.

[image: The delivery date range on the cart page]
The delivery date range on the cart page

[image: The delivery date range on the checkout page. Still displaying correct.]
The delivery date range on the checkout page. Still displaying correct.

[image: The delivery date range on the thankyou page. Here it is displaying wrong.]
The delivery date range on the thankyou page. Here it is displaying wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the function lieferzeit() hooked in the **`woocommerce_thankyou`** action hook, that is not getting the cart data anymore *(as cart has been removed at this step, after checkout)*.

**THE WORKING SOLUTION IS:**

1) **REMOVE THE CODE:** *(remove this line in your code)*:

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'lieferzeit'); // Order recieved
```

2) **ADD THE CODE:** *(for example after `save_delivery_range_in_order_meta()` function)*:

```
// Displays the delivery range values" in Order received (thankyou) page
add_action ( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'get_in_order_received_lieferzeit_data', 100, 1 );
function get_in_order_received_lieferzeit_data( $order_id ) {

    $from = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_delivery_range_from', true );
    $to = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_delivery_range_to', true );

    echo '<i class="shipping_icon fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></i> <div class="lieferung"> Vorauslichtliche Lieferung </div>  <div class="fromto_date"> ' . $from . ' – ' . $to . ' </div> <div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Gilt nur bei Lieferungen nach Deutschland.</span></div>' ;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> **So now you will get the real correct data from the order meta data**

This code is tested and works